# conanfile.py requirements() vs build_requirements() in CMake integration

Tags: cmake, conan, conanfile

I noticed that previously I was using some conan dependencies as **runtime** requirements, but I only need them as **build** requirements, so I started using `build_requirements` function instead

## The upgrade

```
# Runtime level requirements
def requirements(self):
    print("[conanfily.py]: Defining runtime requirements")
    #self.requires("grpc/1.54.3") <---OLD

# Build level requirements
def build_requirements(self):
    print("[conanfily.py]: Defining build requirements")
    self.tool_requires("grpc/1.54.3")
    self.tool_requires("protobuf/3.21.12")
    self.tool_requires("cmake/3.28.1")
```

Previously our build was working by simply calling find_package function in our CMake files

```
# Conan packages are found from conan_toolkit.cmake
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)

# Link the conan imported dependencies
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc++_reflection
    protobuf::libprotobuf
)
```

But it no longer builds if I utilize `build_requirements`

## The Problem:

Now that I switched to use `self.tool_requires`, conan 2 is no longer generating the .cmake files that I need for the find_package function

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at CmdServiceClient/CMakeLists.txt:217 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gRPC" with any of
  the following names:

    gRPCConfig.cmake
    grpc-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gRPC" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gRPC_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gRPC"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.        C:\dev\git\LT-CONTROLLER-SERVICE\app\Service\CmdServiceClient/CMakeLists.txt    217 Build
```

The .cmake files no longer exist, they don't get generated by CMakeDeps for `build_requirements`

## Main Question:

Anyone know how I can make the `generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"` generate .cmake files for `build_requirements` instead of the previous runtime conan `requirements` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conan documentation explicitly says that `tool_requires` are exclusively for tools, executables, like `cmake` or `meson`, and that it shouldn't be used for regular libraries requires. You can read more about this in [this section in the docs](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/methods/build_requirements.html)

The "[Good practices](https://docs.conan.io/2/knowledge/guidelines.html#good-practices)" section also mention this:

> Please, do not abuse ‘tool_requires’. Those are intended only for executables like cmake and ninja running in the “build” context, not for libraries or library-like dependencies, that must use requires or test_requires.

What you are looking for is regular `requires`. Conan 2 can perfectly use libraries only as "build-time", for example if an application links a static library, and the dependency will be marked as "skip" at install time, if it is not needed and downloading the binary for the static library will actually be avoided.You can read more about [requirement traits](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/methods/requirements.html#requirement-traits), [package-type](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#package-type)

Comment: I see. Yes grpc will be required at runtime, so I should use a normal require for it.